# Cast from '(key: String, value: NSObject)' to unrelated type 'Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any?>' always fails

Tags: swift

Should I worry about this warning? or is there something I can do to cast correctly? Im very new to IOS development

> Cast from `(key: String, value: NSObject)` to unrelated type
>   `Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any?>` always fails

```
ADClient.shared().requestAttributionDetails({ (attributionDetails, error) in
        if error == nil {
            for (type, adDictionary) in attributionDetails! {
                var attribution = adDictionary as? Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>;
                let params = [
                    "iadLineitemName": attribution?["iad-lineitem-name"] as? String as Any,
                    "iadOrgName": attribution?["iad-org-name"] as? String as Any

                    ]
              print(params)
            }
        }
})
```

This is the line the warning occurs

```
var attribution = adDictionary as? Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>;
```

Comment: You should worry about it if you want to get any values from `adDictionary` since the downcast will always fail and `adDictionary` will always be `nil`  Why do you have that downcast and what's with the `as? String as Any`?

Comment: @Paulw11 any sugestions what I should do? sorry I am pretty new to IOS Dev

Comment: Get rid of the downcast and conditionally unwrap `attributionDetails` and conditionally unwrap the two values before attempting to put them into the `params` dictionary.

Comment: The error says that you can't cast from a tuple to a dictionary so most likely `attributionDetails` is an array.